# How to write loop in trajectory of Simmer package

Tags: r, loops, queue, simulation

I was trying to simulate a queueing network using R's package Simmer. However, I had trouble incorporating loops in main trajectory. A simple one node queue code is following:

```
to_queue_1 <- trajectory() %>%
for(i in 1:100){
   seize("nurse", 1) %>%
  timeout(1) %>%
   release("nurse", 1)
 }

env <- simmer()
add_resource("nurse",1)
env %>%
add_generator("arrival1_", to_queue_1, function() rexp(1, 1),mon=2) %>%
run(200)
```

After runing the trajectory function, it shows me that "Error in for (. in i) 1:100 : 4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3".

The actual network is more complicated, which requires a loop where different nodes communicate. For example, I want node 1 flows to both node 2 and 3. Node 2 flows to node 1 and 3. Node 3 flows to node 1 and 2. The only possible exit is Node 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `rollback` activity serves this purpose:

```
library(simmer)

to_queue_1 <- trajectory() %>%
  seize("nurse", 1) %>%
  timeout(1) %>%
  release("nurse", 1) %>%
  rollback(3, 100)

env <- simmer() %>%
  add_resource("nurse",1) %>%
  add_generator("arrival1_", to_queue_1, function() rexp(1, 1), mon=2) %>%
  run(200)
```

Where `3` is the number of activities to roll back, and `100` is the number of repetitions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, is it possible to have functional arguments in rollback()? For example, after releasing "nurse", I seize "doctor" and release "doctor". After that, instead of using rollback(3,100), I may want to rollback(1~3,1) with probability p, and rollback(4~6,1) with probability q, exit with probability 1-p-q. Essentially it's a nurse-doctor tandem queue while doctor can send patients back to nurse with some probability.

Comment: The `rollback` activity has an optional argument `check` which overrides the second argument `times` if present, so that every time the `rollback` is reached, it is checked whether it should go back or not.

If you need to roll back a different number of activities depending on some probability, you can use a `branch` and place several `rollback` there.

Comment: Thank you very much!I will check that!